# Why would you use the ruby -l (ELL) flag?

Tags: ruby

from the man pages

> (The lowercase letter ``ell''.)  Enables automatic line-ending
>   processing, which means to firstly set $\ to the value of $/, and
>   secondly chops every line read using chop!.

And I can construct an example of the switch working:

```
➜  ruby-ell cat app.rb
p "hello world"
p "$\: #{$\}"
p "$\: #{$/}"
➜  ruby-ell ruby app.rb
"hello world"
"$: "
"$: \n"
➜  ruby-ell ruby -l app.rb
"hello world"
"$: \n"
"$: \n"
```

So I can see that the `-l` is loading `$/` into `$\` but why would you want to do that? Would love some examples and/or references to instances of this switch being used :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably most useful with **-n** or **-p**. It allows you to edit the current line (`$_`) without caring about the trailing newline. For example, to append "foo" to the end of each line:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3" | ruby -lnpe '$_ << "foo"'
1foo
2foo
3foo
```

Without **-l**, it would append "foo" *after* the newline character:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3" | ruby -npe '$_ << "foo"'
1
foo2
foo3
foo
```

And without setting the record separator, a simple `chop!` would just remove all newlines:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3" | ruby -npe '$_.chop!; $_ << "foo"'
1foo2foo3foo
```

Note that you can specify the input record separator:

```
echo -n "1-2-3-" | ruby -l055 -npe '$_ << "foo"'
1foo
2foo
3foo
```

055 is the octal value for `-`.

You can also specify the output separator via **-0**:

```
echo -n "1-2-3-" | ruby -0056 -l055 -npe '$_ << "foo"'
1foo.2foo.3foo.
```

All these switches come from Perl, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches